# Is there a word for these types of tattoos?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I kept googling "sleeve tattoos", but I can't find sleeve tattoos like the ones in the picture above with that term. Is there a keyword or a word that refers to that particular tattoo style?

Comment: Its not clear the the girl (elf?) in the picture has any tattoos.  I see white, lacy things on her arms, but they don't look like real tattoos.  Can you get a picture that isn't a fantasy painting or photomanipulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sleeve** is the term used for tattoos that cover the entire arm.  Tattoos that cover only part of the arm can be called a **half-sleeve**, although this usually means a tattoo that covers the upper arm and shoulder.

I suppose these could be called **partial sleeve** tattoos, or simply **arm tattoos**.

[Tattoo Lingo](https://www.inkedmag.com/culture/tattoo-lingo)

[100 Arm Tattoos for Women](https://www.thisistattoo.com/feminine-arm-tattoos-for-girls/)

Given the fantasy context, an author writing about these tattoos would probably say something like:

> The fairy had **eldritch, glowing tattoos** on her **upper arms** and her **wrists**.

Comment: The definition of eldritch is weird and sinister or ghostly.

Comment: @blackbird Also "possibly magical in origin", or "otherworldly".  But that's just my personal interpretation.  She seems like a nice fairy -- but you never know.  A bit likely to catch a cold, though, dressed the way she is.